# jQuery right click function block normal menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have trying to build my own right click menu I will bind to stuff like as a admin menu for admins, but when I do it its block my normal browser menu when you right click on your mouse, I can't find out of why.

**Javascript code:**

```
$.admin_panel = {
menu: {
    product: function(product_uuid) {
        console.log('product');

        $(document.createElement('ul'))
        .attr({
            'id' : 'admin_panel-product-'+ product_uuid
        })
        .addClass('admin_panel_menu')
        .append(
            $(document.createElement('li'))
            .append(
                $(document.createElement('a'))
                .attr({
                    'href' : '{backend url}/'+ product_uuid,
                    'target' : '_Blank'
                })
                .html('Edit via backend')
            )
        )
        .appendTo('body');

        $.admin_panel.tricker.bindEvent('#admin_panel-product-'+ product_uuid);
        $.admin_panel.tricker.mousedownEvent('#admin_panel-product-'+ product_uuid);
        $.admin_panel.tricker.clickEvent('#admin_panel-product-'+ product_uuid);
    }
},

tricker: {
    bindEvent: function(menu_id) {
        console.log('bindEvent');

        $('.admin_panel').bind('contextmenu', function (event) {
            //  event.preventDefault();

             $(menu_id).finish().toggle(100).

             css({
                     top: event.pageY + "px",
                     left: event.pageX + "px"
             });
        });
    },

    mousedownEvent: function(menu_id) {
        console.log('mousedownEvent');

        $(document).bind("mousedown", function (e) {
            if (!$(e.target).parents(menu_id).length > 0) {
                $(menu_id).hide(100);
            }
        });
    },

    clickEvent: function(menu_id) {
        console.log('clickEvent');

        $(menu_id +" li").click(function(){
        $(menu_id).hide(100);
      });
    }
},

run: function() {
    console.log('Admin panel run! :)');

    $.each($('.admin_panel'), function(index, value) {
        switch(true) {
            case $(value).hasClass('admin_panel_product'):
                $.admin_panel.menu.product($(value).data('product-uuid'));
                break;
        }
    });
    }
};
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<h1 class="h2 admin_panel admin_panel_product admin_panel_obj_b6672e48-a99f-49f4-a46b-8197686c8935" data-product-uuid="b6672e48-a99f-49f4-a46b-8197686c8935">product title here</h1>
```

**CSS by SCSS syntax**

```
.admin_panel_menu {
    display: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #333;
    border-radius: 5px;

        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;

        li {
            padding: 6px 12px;
            cursor: pointer;
                font-size: 12px;

                &:hover {
                    background-color: #DEF;
                }
        }
}
```

**Run the code**

```
$.admin_panel.run();
```

Its shut only work when i click on this admin_panel area, not orther place.

Comment: Could it be because of that call to `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Post some `html` too!!

Comment: no prevent not do eny deffriend, and i have now updated the code.

Comment: Can you post the complete JS code, please ? It seems there's something's missing like binding between your HTML and `admin_panel`

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But are you sure that you have posted enough code ? I've tested what you posted and the normal context menu of the browser is displayed everytime anywhere on the page (IE11)

Comment: Sorry forgotten CSS code, i post it now in SCSS syntax.

Comment: Do you want the normal context menu of the browser to be blocked when right click occuer on the `h2` tag ?

Comment: Yeah what i want its when i right click on h2 tag, its my custom menu there will be showing, and if you click outside the h2 tag will the normal browser context menu be showing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For showing your context menu only on the `h2` tag and "disabling" the normal context menu of the browser only in this case, you only have to add `return false;` in the end of your `contextmenu` event handler.

So your code should look like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.admin_panel.run();
});


$.admin_panel = {
menu: {
    product: function(product_uuid) {
        console.log('product');

        $(document.createElement('ul'))
        .attr({
            'id' : 'admin_panel-product-'+ product_uuid
        })
        .addClass('admin_panel_menu')
        .append(
            $(document.createElement('li'))
            .append(
                $(document.createElement('a'))
                .attr({
                    'href' : '{backend url}/'+ product_uuid,
                    'target' : '_Blank'
                })
                .html('Edit via backend')
            )
        )
        .appendTo('body');

        $.admin_panel.tricker.bindEvent('#admin_panel-product-'+ product_uuid);
        $.admin_panel.tricker.mousedownEvent('#admin_panel-product-'+ product_uuid);
        $.admin_panel.tricker.clickEvent('#admin_panel-product-'+ product_uuid);
    }
},

tricker: {
    bindEvent: function(menu_id) {
        console.log('bindEvent');

        $('.admin_panel').bind('contextmenu', function (event) {
            //  event.preventDefault();

             $(menu_id).finish().toggle(100).

             css({
                     top: event.pageY + "px",
                     left: event.pageX + "px"
             });
          
          return false;
        });
    },

    mousedownEvent: function(menu_id) {
        console.log('mousedownEvent');

        $(document).bind("mousedown", function (e) {
            if (!$(e.target).parents(menu_id).length > 0) {
                $(menu_id).hide(100);
            }
        });
    },

    clickEvent: function(menu_id) {
        console.log('clickEvent');

        $(menu_id +" li").click(function(){
        $(menu_id).hide(100);
      });
    }
},

run: function() {
    console.log('Admin panel run! :)');

    $.each($('.admin_panel'), function(index, value) {
        switch(true) {
            case $(value).hasClass('admin_panel_product'):
                $.admin_panel.menu.product($(value).data('product-uuid'));
                break;
        }
    });
    }
};
```

```css
.admin_panel_menu {
    display: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #333;
    border-radius: 5px;

        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;

        li {
            padding: 6px 12px;
            cursor: pointer;
                font-size: 12px;

                &:hover {
                    background-color: #DEF;
                }
        }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="h2 admin_panel admin_panel_product admin_panel_obj_b6672e48-a99f-49f4-a46b-8197686c8935" data-product-uuid="b6672e48-a99f-49f4-a46b-8197686c8935">product title here</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, so awsome to know :) now i have a cool day agin, thanks by you :D